# Unexplainable ClassNotFoundException in server unmanaged thread

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception, websphere-8, apache-commons-io

I am facing a weird `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` under the following circumstances:

I have a web application running in Websphere Application Server 8.0 that uses commons-io 2.0.1 (this jar is correctly placed in the classpath).

I am using `org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer` to tail a log file and show its contents on screen. Tailer implements Runnable so it runs in its own Thread.

On application shutdown I invoke tailer.stop() to stop the Thread. Then the last thing that Tailer executes is a finally block in which it closes the log reader.

```
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
}
```

When it executes that line there's a `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`.

I've made some tests adding some code into Tailer class (and replacing it in the jar) to determine if it's a ClassLoader issue:

**1. Determine Tailer's resource:**

`Tailer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.class");`

> **Output**: `wsjar:file:/home/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar!/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.class`
>   which is the right jar

**2. What classloader is it using?:**
`Tailer.class.getClassLoader();`

> `com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@8d336acd[war:application/myApp.war]` Again this is correct.

**3. Try to load IOUtils directly from the previous ClassLoader:**
`Tailer.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");`

> Again a ClassNotFoundException

**4. Now, the most surprising thing: if I add a Class.forName() like below at the beginning of the run method, the class is correctly loaded and now the IOUtils call in the finally block works. How come??**

```
public void run() {
     RandomAccessFile reader = null;
     try {
         Class.forName("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }         
     try {
         ...
         while (run) {
            ...
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         listener.handle(e);
     } finally {
         IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
     }
 }

 /**
 * Allows the tailer to complete its current loop and return.
 */
 public void stop() {
     this.run = false;
 }
```

It doesn't make any sense! It is using Tailer from commons-io-2.0.1.jar but it isn't it able to use a class that it's inside the very same jar. But if you force a load of the class at the beginning of the run(), then it doesn't fail anymore. Any ideas?

This is the whole stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-88" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer.run(Tailer.java:319)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:703)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:123)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items #1 and #2 are simply data points that show that common problems are not the cause. They are not necessarily indicative of the source of the issue.

Item #3 is indicative of the issue. It would seem that based on that item, the classes have already been unloaded from memory at that point. I looked through for some documentation that would show under what conditions ClassLoader would throw an exception, but was unable to find any. So, I am guessing that classes have been unloaded and the state of the application is such that the warfile itself has been freed. Further guesses are irrelevant.

Item #4 is indeed curious. The documentation on Class.forName says "Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application." and "Class has no public constructor. Instead Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.". Which seems to mean that even if the Class has been unloaded from memory Class.forName should be able to load it.

Item #4 in your example, does not have Class.forName in the finally block. I assume that is simply an artifact of the pasted code and that you did in fact place it there and it threw an error.

Update : After discussing with the OP, The following suggestion does the job.
At the point of invocation of tailer.stop(), place a thread.sleep() for a few seconds after the call. This should allow enough time for the finally call to finish up (closeQuietly(reader)) before the Application has been unloaded from the ClassLoader.

Comment: Regarding #4: I didn't place an aditional Class.forName() in the finally block. The one at the beginning of the run method was enough so that the finally block doesn't throw an exception. That's the strange thing: one Class.forName in the run() and then the call to IOUtils works like a charm

Comment: In that case, isn't it possible that the Class.forName() works because the application has not been unloaded as yet. If it works in the finally block before or after the call to IOUtils it would be an interesting data point.

Comment: I think you made a good point regarding the unloading of the classes. Furthermore, the fact that reloading the IOUtils class in every loop iteration prevents the failure seems to point that way: the class is not discarded by the classloader.
By the way, if the Class.forName() is only in the finally block it fails.

Comment: I see. In that case, what seems to be happening is that the WebApp and Tailer are separate even though they are using the same ClassLoader. The WebApp is unaware that there is still a resource referencing the classes loaded in the war. Shuts down before the finally block can be reached in the Tailer. One way of handling this is to call tailer.stop() and then wait for some seconds. It doesnt look like the finally method will take that much time to finish up anyways. The other option is to look for a way to notify the WebApp that there is still a resource referencing it.

Comment: Sleeping the thread after `tailer.stop()` did it! Thanks for your support! If you update your answer with this info I'll accept it